# Error in find_in_batches rails db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rake task in which im trying to get all the values from my old_work_orders table..
This is my task..

```
OldWorkOrder.find_in_batches do |group|
  p group
end
```

and im getting an error like this..

rake aborted!

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'old_work_orders.' in 'order clause': SELECT  `old_work_orders`.* FROM `old_work_orders`   ORDER BY `old_work_orders`.`` ASC LIMIT 1000
```

and in model name old_work_order.rb

```
class OldWorkOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

and my db got values in it also..

Comment: version of rails/active_record?

Comment: Sounds like you don't have a primary key (or at least rails thinks you don't)

Comment: Can you post your `old_work_orders` table `schema`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the Model you are using has no primary key 
solution is quite easy

Only for this query purpose

define

```
class OldWorkOrder < ActiveRecord::Base   
   self.primary_key = :id
end
```

and then use

```
OldWorkOrder.find_in_batches do |group| 
    p group
 end
```